# How to restrict certain users from adding files to a certain folder?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I would like to restrict a group of users from adding documents to a specific folder. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can restrict a group of users from adding documents to a specific folder.

You can set unique permission for the folders.

Choose the folder->in File tab, choose shared with->advanced->stop inheriting permissions->then you can remove user's permission or set read permission for the users.

[image]

[image]

Customize permissions for a SharePoint list or library:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/customize-permissions-for-a-sharepoint-list-or-library-02d770f3-59eb-4910-a608-5f84cc297782